# Snowflake - Run Multiple SQL Queries at Once

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's PRETEND, I am using SQL Server, if I execute the following queries, they will go one after the next:

```
select top 10 * from table_1;
go
select top 10 * from table_2;
go
select top 10 * from table_3;
go
```

Snowflake does not have a `go` command, and it appears to only execute the last statement only.

Is there a way to make all 3 (or whatever my number is) run instead of just the last one running?

**Edit #1:**

I am using the Snowflake Web UI

Comment: in the webui you click the "run all commands" and it queues/runs all commands.

Comment: as Simeon says - it all depends in what UI or API you are using - but Snowflake can run these in parallel

Comment: Edited my post, I am using the Web UI, let me look for that option somewhere. Thank you!

Comment: Simeon: you solved my problem, post as the answer and I'll mark it as so?

Answer (score 4):

There is no go command in snowflake. however, you can execute multiple queries at the same time from the WEB UI of the snowflake. Please find the sql below

```
select top 10 * from table_1;

select top 10 * from table_2;

select top 10 * from table_3;
```

Select all the above queries and click on execute. Each query will have the query id and result set to view.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like DBVisualizer that lets you run a script and see the results of all the queries executed, each in their own tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of *SnowSQL* and submit use the command below, that will submit the queries asynchronously:

```
snowsql -o log_level=DEBUG -q "select top 10 * from table_1;> select top 10 * from table_2;> select top 10 * from table_3;"
```